# Github Actions API - Get person who approved the deployment on an environment

Tags: github-actions, github-api

I am having a hard time trying to find where I can get the person who approved the deployment on GithubActions API.

There is an [API to POST approve/reject](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#review-custom-deployment-protection-rules-for-a-workflow-run) , but no HTTP GET

Basically, it is the person marked on the image below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this workflow run approval from a public/private fork?

Comment: This workflow approval is from a github enterprise private repo. The approval is for the deployment on a environment, as defined in "required reviewers". I attached another image on the question showing the environment configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see approvals for a workflow run with [`/repos/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/{run_id}/approvals`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-review-history-for-a-workflow-run);

For the [example workflow provided in the screenshot](https://github.com/guilhermecgs/actions/actions/runs/4939224294);

```bash
# gh api /repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/actions/runs/{RUN_ID}/approvals
gh api /repos/guilhermecgs/actions/actions/runs/4939224294/approvals
```

You can `jq` this to just get the name of the person, for an approval, limiting the results to approvals of a specific environment;

```bash
gh api /repos/guilhermecgs/actions/actions/runs/4939224294/approvals --jq \
'.[] | select (.environments[] != null) | select(.environments[].name == "prd") | .user.login'
```

You can also query the deployments at [`/repos/guilhermecgs/actions/deployments`](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/deployments/deployments?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-deployments);

```bash
# gh api /repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/deployments?environment={ENV}
gh api /repos/guilhermecgs/actions/deployments?environment=prd
```

If you also know the commit sha that the workflow ran on from which the deployment was made, you can query on that and `jq` those results;

```bash
# gh api /repos/{OWNER}/{REPO}/deployments?environment={ENV}\&sha={COMMIT_SHA}
gh api /repos/guilhermecgs/actions/deployments?environment=prd\
\&sha=d2000155e0d7a65e4e159b828951890f2658f371 \
--jq '.[].creator.login'
```

The example workflow seems to have been run three times for that combination of environment and sha, so the deployments api will give you all three of those deployments, but doesn't tie them to a workflow from which they were triggered.